# Spring boot feign client integration test configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, integration-testing, openfeign

Good day 
I am trying to write Feign specific integration test and have specific configuration to enable feign auto configuration it looks like that

```
@Profile({Profiles.FEIGN_INTEGRATION_TEST, Profiles.PROD, Profiles.DEV, Profiles.STAGE})
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
public class FeignEnabler {
}
```

and in my test (Spock specification)

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.FEIGN_INTEGRATION_TEST)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

   @Subject
   @Autowired
   MyService myService
}
```

`MyService` is using `RestClient`

```
@Profile({Profiles.FEIGN_INTEGRATION_TEST, Profiles.PROD, Profiles.DEV, Profiles.STAGE})
@FeignClient(name = "myRestClient", url = "${feign.client.config.myclient.url}")
public interface RestClient
```

Sadly, running test specification exception appears

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapplication.web.RestClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Workout for that problem would be to add `@EnableFeignClients` in `@SpringBootApplication` class, but this way it messes with another tests (in my case DataJpa slice tests) and to avoid it I need to add this line of code

```
@ImportAutoconfiguration({RibbonAutoConfiguration.class, FeignRibbonClientAutoConfiguration.class, FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
```

as described here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7270 for each integration test, not using FeignAutoConfiguration and I really don't want to do that...

Comment: I don't think `@Profile` works on `@FeignClient`.

Comment: @spencergibb Actually it works , tried that in code :)

Comment: Why can't you have `@SpringBootTest` point to a separate configuration for the feign specific tests?

Comment: @artjomka, what is the solution you came up with? I have also a similar scenario. Thanks!